# React Native Adjust implementation throwing status code as 0 in iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to implement the [Adjust](https://help.adjust.com/en/developer) SDK in both Android and iOS.  In Android it is working fine, but the same code not working on iOS.

Following is my Adjust integration but if I console log status, I am getting status value as 0

I thought this is because of the Emulator issue, then did the build and tried it on real device but still getting the same issue. I am not sure what I am missing here

```
var adjustEvent = new AdjustEvent("xyzabc");
      Adjust.trackEvent(adjustEvent);
      Adjust.updateConversionValue(6);
      Adjust.getAppTrackingAuthorizationStatus((status) => {
        console.log("Authorization status = " + status);
      });
```

Comment: Did you follow the iOS setup?

Comment: @Shivo'ham yes I did.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription` to be able to request for permission to track user.

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>Privacy - Tracking Usage Description</string>
```

2. After that you need to call `Adjust.requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler` like the example below:

```js
Adjust.trackEvent(adjustEvent);
Adjust.updateConversionValue(6);
Adjust.getAppTrackingAuthorizationStatus(status => {
  if (status === 0) {
    console.error('Adjust SDK Error: Authorization status returned 0.');
    // Additional error handling or fallback logic here
    Adjust.requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler(_status => {
      console.log('Authorization status updated:', {status: _status});
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Authorization status = ' + status);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Since iOS 14+, you need to [request permission to track the user](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/). The status code 0 might indicate a permission issue. Make sure you have implemented the ATT framework correctly.

The first step to debug this would be with better error handling:

```js
var adjustEvent = new AdjustEvent("xyzabc");
Adjust.trackEvent(adjustEvent);
Adjust.updateConversionValue(6);
Adjust.getAppTrackingAuthorizationStatus((status) => {
  if (status === 0) {
    console.error("Adjust SDK Error: Authorization status returned 0.");
    // Additional error handling or fallback logic here
  } else {
    console.log("Authorization status = " + status);
  }
});
```